# Steam fails to launch after installing OpenGL drivers

Tags: steam, opengl

I just installed steam and downloaded some games. Then I updated the OpenGL drivers for the integrated graphics. After that, steam wouldn't start. It opens the updating steam window and then immediately closes. Running steam from terminal gives this output:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "gail"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)

** (steam:6713): WARNING **: Unknown device type 14

** (steam:6713): WARNING **: Could not create object for /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1: unknown object type
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 769
Steam_SetMinidumpSteamID:  Caching Steam ID:  76561198127529751 [API loaded no]
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1496897923)
assert_20170620212943_1.dmp[6767]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20170620212943_1.dmp
/home/jeremy/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 727:  6713 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20170620212943_1.dmp[6767]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20170620212943_1.dmp[6767]: response: CrashID=bp-37e580d3-2447-4472-806c-05c0b2170620
assert_20170620212943_1.dmp[6767]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20170620212943_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-37e580d3-2447-4472-806c-05c0b2170620''
Assert( CClientPipe::BWriteAndReadResult: BWaitResult failed, disconnected ):../common/pipes.cpp:765

crash_20170620212946_2.dmp[6771]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/crash_20170620212946_2.dmp
crash_20170620212946_2.dmp[6771]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
crash_20170620212946_2.dmp[6771]: response: Discarded=1
crash_20170620212946_2.dmp[6771]: file ''/tmp/dumps/crash_20170620212946_2.dmp'', upload yes: ''Discarded=1''
../common/pipes.cpp (765) : CClientPipe::BWriteAndReadResult: BWaitResult failed, disconnected
steamclient.cpp (714) : Assertion Failed: bufRet.TellPut() == sizeof(uint8)
../common/processpipe_posix.cpp (492) : Assertion Failed: CCrossProcessPipe::BWrite: 32 (Broken pipe)
```

Comment: `sudo apt purge --auto-remove steam` then download steam from the oficial webpage and install steam again, all the game are stored in your home directory so just copy the steamapps folder out of the .steam folder and use the command for removing that

Answer (score 0):

Steam is almost impossible to run without proprietary drivers (in my experience).  You should be able to re-install them through:

System Settings... --> Software & Updates --> Additional Drivers